# Looking for open source user management and billing PHP web site code

Tags: php, open-source, user-management, login-script

I need to create a website in which users login, see certain reports, customize, pay (via paypal and credit card) etc. 
80% of this is similar to many websites (including stackoverflow)

Do you know of a user management code (PHP) that I can use as starting point to save time?

Drupal seems to be able to provide what I want but I want something lighter that I can change and skin easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal isn't actually so heavy, and has ready modules to do what you want (and more).

Alternatively you might build your own solution on top of CakePHP, CodeIgniter, Zend or similar framework, which include plenty of ready stuff so that you don't need to completely re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://jplpinto.com/apis/test/filemanager/homepage/homepage.php 
you can integrate it with some user script (eg. http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html ) and edit that so you can bill it.